# Cambiar fechas en Español con Python

Tags: python, date, csv, datetime, parser

Tengo un problema a la hora de leer y posteriormente guardar un CSV en Python.
El CSV origen contiene las fechas de la siguiente forma: mes abreviado en español + año (ej. "AGO 2019). Necesito convertir estas fechas al formato `"%d/%m/%Y"` y como la variable %m solo entiende meses en ingles hago el siguiente parser:

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "es_ES")

class LocaleParserInfo(parser.parserinfo):
    MONTHS = [('Ene', 'Enero'), ('Feb', 'Febrero'), ('Mar', 'Marzo'), ('Abr', 'Abril'), 
              ('May', 'Mayo'), ('Jun', 'Junio'), ('Jul', 'Julio'), ('Ago', 'Agosto'), 
              ('Sep', 'Sept', 'Septiembre'), ('Oct', 'Octubre'), ('Nov', 'Noviembre'), ('Dic', 
               'Diciembre')]
time_example = parser.parse('Ago-2019', parserinfo=LocaleParserInfo())
print (time_example.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Obteniendo como resultado `25/08/2019`

Mi problema es: ¿por qué me escribe el día 25? Realmente yo necesito el día `01/08/2019`

Comment: Buen día, escribe 25 porque es el día de hoy, como no le indicas día lo toma como referencia, si quieres que sea el primero de cada mes, escribe `01`

Comment: Por cierto, tienes otra pregunta que ha sido respondida y no has aceptado la respuesta o indicado que hay un problema con ella. Por favor revisa tus preguntas anteriores

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta  @HeytalePazguato , el problema que tengo es que en el CSV no vienen informados los dias, solo se informa el mes abreviado es español + año y necesito que me escriba el dia 01 por defecto, no el dia en el que ejecuto el script.

Comment: PD: no se que tengo que hacer para aceptar una respuesta. Soy usuaria nueva en stackoverflow

Comment: Si el año no viene en el CSV es muy fácil, puedes escribir `01` para todas las fechas.

Comment: Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)